# Django Edit Profile - 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: django, templates, django-models, django-forms

So I just followed [this](https://blog.khophi.co/extending-django-user-model-userprofile-like-a-pro/) tutorial to create a profile for a user and allow them to edit it but I get this error when I go and visit the edit page `'bool' object is not callable`

```
File "C:\Users\...\account\userprofile\views.py", line 64, in profile_edit_view
   if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.id == user.id:
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = "account/userprofile/photos", verbose_name="Profile Picture", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
        user_profile.save()
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

views.py

```
def profile_edit_view(request, pk):
    # querying the User object with pk from url
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

    # prepopulate UserProfileForm with retrieved user values from above.
    user_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=user)

    # The sorcery begins from here, see explanation below
    ProfileInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(User, UserProfile, fields=('location', 'website', 'bio'))
    formset = ProfileInlineFormset(instance=user)

    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.id == user.id:
        if request.method == "POST":
            user_form = ProfileEditForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
            formset = ProfileInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)

            if user_form.is_valid():
                created_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                formset = ProfileInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=created_user)

                if formset.is_valid():
                    created_user.save()
                    formset.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')

        return render(request, "account/account_update.html", {
            "noodle": pk,
            "noodle_form": user_form,
            "formset": formset,
        })
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`User.is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) is a Boolean value, so you should not call it as a function. Remove the parentheses and it will work as expected:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.id == user.id:
```