# how to fix 'PluginReferenceField' object has no attribute 'rel' fields.py from djangocms-forms

Tags: django, django-cms

```py
class PluginReferenceField(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'null': True})  # always allow Null
        kwargs.update({'editable': False})  # never allow edits in admin
        kwargs.update({'on_delete': SET_NULL})  # never delete plugin
        super(PluginReferenceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _create(self, model_instance):
        return self.rel.to._default_manager.create(name=model_instance.name)

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        if not model_instance.pk and add:
            setattr(model_instance, self.name, self._create(model_instance))
        else:
            reference = getattr(model_instance, self.name)
            if not reference:
                setattr(model_instance, self.name, self._create(model_instance))
                reference = getattr(model_instance, self.name)
            if reference.name != model_instance.name:
                reference.name = model_instance.name
                reference.save()
        return super(PluginReferenceField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)
```

Comment: What versions of django/django-cms/djangocms-forms are you using? Who's code is this, is it yours, or part of a package?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issues after setting up [djangocms](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/introduction/install.html) and installing [djangocms-forms](https://github.com/mishbahr/djangocms-forms).

It looks like "rel.to" has been depreciated in 2.0. See ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24317

On lines 66-67 of fields.py for the djangocms_forms package, change

```
def _create(self, model_instance):
    return self.rel.to._default_manager.create(name=model_instance.name)
```

to

```
def _create(self, model_instance):
    return self.related_model._default_manager.create(name=model_instance.name)
```

You may also need to remove the "()" for "user.is_authenticated" in forms.py:348 after the fact. I needed to do further debugging, as I encountered [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000345/django-edit-profile-bool-object-is-not-callable) immediately after.

I was able to get djangocms-forms working successfully on Django version 3.1.4.